# How to calculate a gradient at x=0?

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a second order differential equation for n[x]. I solved it with both DSolve and NDSolve. A plot of n as a function of x looks great. Than **I want to calculate a gradient of n[x] at  a point x=0 and plot it as a function of V. I don't know how to execute this.** I calculated gradient at every point and plot it. I get expected shape of the curve and there is also V on x axis, but the values of y axis are to high. Here is the code:

```
eq = Gx + D[Dif*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(n[x]\)\), x] - 
    Kr (n[x] - n0) == 0;
bcs = {n'[d] == 0, n[0] == n0*Exp[(e \[Alpha] V)/(kb T)]};
\[Alpha] = 0.25;
e = 1.602*10^-19;
kb = 1.38*10^-23;
T = 300;
d = 20*10^-6;
Gx = 10^17;
Dif = 4*10^-9;
Kr = 3.1*10^-9;
n0 = 10^21;
sol := {V, 
  D[#, x] &@
   NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, n[x], {x, 0, d}, MaxSteps -> 50000][[1, 1, 2]]}
res = Table[sol, {V, 0, 0.7, 0.05}];
ListPlot[Table[res, {x, 0, d}], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

Gx is a complicated function of x because I integrate a list as input. So, my result of DSolve is very big.

I need to stop the calculation of gradient as soon as it becomes zero. When the plot of n'[x] at x=0 cross the x axis (with values of V on it) my calculation should stop and the appropriate result (graph) should be displayed. I don't need the negative values of the derivative, so there is no need for Mathematica for further calculations. What is the best way to execute this?

But I have another problem there because my result is to high and it never changes the sign. In theory it should..

My result should look like:

Because I cannot post the images, you can see the desired graph on the link:
https://www.google.si/search?hl=sl&rlz=1C1TEUA_enSI493SI493&q=current+voltage+characteristics+DSSC&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&biw=1600&bih=785&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=YspCUb3GFYvUsgaTnYGoCA#imgrc=wX5CgAQmm0sdkM%3A%3BJbeOH9F0mOvjNM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fars.els-cdn.com%252Fcontent%252Fimage%252F1-s2.0-S0025540812004047-gr9.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.sciencedirect.com%252Fscience%252Farticle%252Fpii%252FS0025540812004047%3B384%3B314

On x axis is voltage, on y axis is current density, which I should calculate from the gradient at a point x=0: J=(dn[x]/dx)x=0. The current is related to a density gradient, the diffusion coefficient being the proportionality constant. But if I multiply the resulted derivative with Dif, it doesn't change enough. If I multiply the whole equation with e, which gives me correct units, the result is too small.

From the picture above is evident, that my values on y axis are changing to slowly.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why do you say it is too high?

Comment: Your code seems right. If your result for the derivative are much higher than you expected, perhaps you could check those constants.

Comment: You can see analytically from the DSolve solution that this is correct. Why do you think that this is the wrong answer?

Comment: I want to observe a current density. It is the gradient that I am calculating. But I should multiply my result by a proportionality factor Dif, which changes the result but not enough. The current density cannot have so high values. It is true, that also the units are not correct. I should multiply the result for gradient by elementary charge to get the current. But even I do this, the values are not ok. I must also find a way to stop the calculation, when my gradient (current density) is zero. I think If loop will do it. But first, I want to be sure, my calculation is correct..

Comment: You can use the command *AspectRatio* if you just want to change the scale between the axes, for more see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AspectRatio.html)

Comment: The Table[res, {x, 0, d}] seems to be a little bit off, right now, because of the very small value of d, it takes only one value $x=0$. Is that what you want? If not you need to give an adequate step for that table too.

Comment: @Luka what do you mean by saying " I must also find a way to stop the calculation, when my gradient (current density) is zero."? You should also put that in your question.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Thank you for helpful comments. So, now I know, why my plot result is for the value x=0. I want the result for that value right now, but I will be thankful if you tell me how to change the Table command. By stopping the calculation, I mean, that I need just the positive values of the derivative. So, when the calculated gradient is zero, the further result is not any more important to me. I hope, I explained it enough. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Luka for the table you can give something like      Table[res, {x, 0, d, d/10}] to get 10+1 values for $x$. As for your second question the easy way is to use the function _TakeWhile_: (TakeWhile[#, #[[2]] > 0&]&/@ Table[res, {x, 0, d, d/10}])/.{} -> 
  Sequence[]. The substitution {}->Sequence[] removes any empty lists ({}) from the list of points.This is not of course the best solutions with respect to efficiency and speed if you want I can provider a more complicated solution including Do, Break and Reap and Sow ...

Comment: Still I don't get what you want to represent on the graph can you clarify that part? What are the values of  y axes?

Comment: @Spawn1701D I think I should figure the result out by myself, you helped me enough. There must be problems with some other thing (units, constants ..) I haven't realized till now and it is not related to use of Mathematica. I will use your TakeWhile command from your comment in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following

```
eq = Gx + D[Dif*n'[x], x] -  Kr (n[x] - n0) == 0
bcs = {n'[d] == 0, n[0] == n0*Exp[(e α V)/(kb T)]};
α = 0.25;
e = 1.602*10^-19;
kb = 1.38*10^-23;
T = 300;
d = 20*10^-6;
Gx = 10^17;
Dif = 4*10^-9;
Kr = 3.1*10^-9;
n0 = 10^21;
sol := {V, 
D[#, x] &@NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, n[x], {x, 0, d}, MaxSteps -> 50000][[1, 1, 2]]}
res = Table[sol, {V, 0, 0.7, 0.05}];
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ListPlot[(TakeWhile[#, #[[2]] > 0&]&/@(Table[#, {x, 0, d, d/100}]&/@Thread[{x, res[[All, 2]]}]))/.{}->Sequence[], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, PlotLegend -> res[[All, 1]], LegendLabel -> "V", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```